# Python calls error (Not enough parameters for the SQL statement) when CSV is still laoding with data

Tags: python, mysql, csv

**Idea:**

My goal is to look for changes in CSV using number of rows detected and compare the new value to old value. If there is a change, then send all CSV data to a MySQL table.

**Problem**

First of all, the code runs perfectly fine when the CSV file is not touched and full of data.

But we have a software that loads thousands of data into CSV (takes approx 1 Minute to load all data into CSV). Every time the software is executed, it deletes the current data and loads the new data again.

Whilst the software is loading data into the CSV file, Python then detects a change in CSV and throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Database Test\Database.py", line 83, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Database Test\Database.py", line 72, in start
    mySQLcursor2.execute('insert into fms (customer_code,customer_logo, product_code,product_description,allergen_info, barcode_inner, barcode_outer, ingredients, EnergyKJ, EnergyKCAL, Fat, Saturates, Carbohydrates, Sugars, Fibre, Protein, salt) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);', row)
  File "C:\Users\LV98\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 558, in execute
    stmt = RE_PY_PARAM.sub(psub, stmt)
  File "C:\Users\LB98\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 85, in __call__
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
```

But if I run the `.py` script after CSV data is still and loaded - it runs normal.

Basically it script does not work when CSV data is been loaded.

**Code:**

```
def countRows():
    prev_rowcount_CSV = None
    while True:
        ###CSV
        file = open('C:/Users/LV98/Desktop/Database Test/FMSExport.csv')
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        lines = len(list(reader))

        if lines != prev_rowcount_CSV and prev_rowcount_CSV != None:
            print("CSV Change")
            #Truncate FMS table in MySQL database
            truncateFMS()

            mySQLcursor1 = mysqlConnection.cursor()
            with open('G:/Technical/Labels/Production/Data/FMSExport.csv', 'r') as f:
                data = csv.reader(f)
                next(data, None)
                for row in data:
                    mySQLcursor1.execute('insert into fms (customer_code,customer_logo, product_code,product_description,allergen_info, barcode_inner, barcode_outer, ingredients, EnergyKJ, EnergyKCAL, Fat, Saturates, Carbohydrates, Sugars, Fibre, Protein, salt) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);', row)
            mysqlConnection.commit()
            mySQLcursor1.close()

            prev_rowcount_CSV = lines

            #Repeat this function every X seconds
            time.sleep(10 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 10))

countRows()
```

**Question:**

I'd like this code to work even when the CSV data is still being loaded with data. How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you intending to use "next(data, None)" to skip a CSV-header row? And does the header row also have 17 values? Or does it have less?

Comment: @Wieger just to skip headers - And definitely 17 headers.

Comment: If the header has 17 values and all other rows normally have 17 values then I guess some row from the CSV is not always written at once but sometimes partially? Is the software which exports the CSV FileMaker Server? Can't the Python script just be executed by the software each time the CSV has finished the export?

Comment: @Wieger I am not sure - it's not our software and won't give us any details :\ but I suppose I can look into executing the code when the software's process has started/finished.

Comment: You could also try to rename the file until it succeeds, then process that file? Files which are opened for writing can't be renamed I guess? (this way you wouldn't have to change the software out of your control)

Comment: Another option: keep reading lines, if less than 17 values, glue the next line, still less, glue next line, until 17 values are present, then parse the CSV values. Though processing a file without it being opened by another process might be a safer bet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from reading and writing to the same file at the same time.

From your comments `repeat this function every X seconds` and
`approx 1 Minute to load all data` and
 `deletes the current data and loads the new`
It sounds, pretty much, **guaranteed** that during the time that your loop is generating sql statements the file from which it is reading data will change?  And thus will read an incomplete row, and thus will fail.

Options might be:

1. Change the filename with every write.  You seem to suggest this out of your control.  You might want to push back on that because this is the simplest and arguably most sensible solution. Or
2. Separate the writing of the file from the processing of the file.  For example, is the time between writes actually long enough to copy the file?  If so, do that, then process the copy. You probably want to do that with a separate script.  One which detects when to copy the file, and does it, independently of this script. I'm not sure how you'd do that on windows, but first idea that comes to mind is a loop which watches the timestamp on the file and when it changes, hopefully that signals a completed write, and make the copy at that moment.  Or
3. Catch the exception, commit what you got up to there, then start over again.

```
        file = open('C:/Users/LV98/Desktop/Database Test/FMSExport.csv')
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        lines = len(list(reader))

        try:
             # all that inner stuff
        except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as ex:
            # oops, we didnt finish
        finally:
            # capture what we have
            mysqlConnection.commit()
            mySQLcursor1.close()

        continue
```

By the sound of it you may never actually process a complete file?

4. Will the whole file fit in memory?  Perhaps, rather than trying to read from the file and write to the database at the same time, you load the whole file into memory, then generate and commit your SQL to the DB.  Thus, assuming you load the whole thing into memory before it starts to change again, it can start rewriting the file and you won't care, because you have a snapshot of the previous version in memory to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Is some outside process replacing the file?

Instead of directly loading from the file, rename the file first.  Then `LOAD` from the renamed file.  This should nearly always avoid getting stepped on.

If something else is leading to the problem, please explain.